# copy and write one html file per image in c - fwrite

Tags: c, algorithm, fwrite

im still trying to find out how i could let the program write one html file per image, my first idea was to do it over iteration of n in the comment below, but i get compiler error because fwrite accepts only 2 arguments, is there any other possibility to do this ? thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main() {
    int i;
    char html[] = {"<html><head><style>img{height:40px;width:40px;}</style></head><body><div align='center'>"};
    char htmlend[] = {"</div></body></html>"};
    char image[] = {"<img src='\\C:\\Users\\Sparkm4n\\Desktop\\material\\\0"};
    char imageend[] = {"'><br>\0"};
    size_t bytes;
    FILE *read;
    FILE *write;
    read = fopen("C:\\Users\\Sparkm4n\\Desktop\\material\\dateien.txt", "r");
    if (read == NULL) {
        printf("read error!\n");
    } else {
        printf("file opened\n");
    }
    char line[200] = {};
    int n = 0;
    write = fopen("C:\\Users\\Sparkm4n\\Desktop\\material\\pics.html", "w");
    printf("pics.html opened %p\n", write);
    fwrite(html, 1, strlen(html), write);
    while (fgets(line, 200, read)) {
        printf("%s\n", line);
        ++n;
        //write=fopen("C:\\Users\\Sparkm4n\\Desktop\\material\\pics",[n],".html", "w"); this one doesnt work
        fwrite(image, 1, strlen(image), write);
        fwrite(line, 1, strlen(line), write);
        fwrite(imageend, 1, 1 + strlen(imageend), write);
    }
    fwrite(htmlend, 1, strlen(htmlend), write);
    printf("%d found\n", n);
    fclose(read);
    fclose(write);
}
```

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: First thing to do is to format your code properly. Second, clarify your question - what exactly is the error and why do you say "fwrite accepts only 2 arguments" when it in fact it is defined to takes 4 arguments?

Comment: the program should create one html file per image, the code that doesnt work is in the comment, is there any other possibility to do this without using fwrite because it accepts only 2 arguments

Comment: Your string initializations like `char htmlend[] = {"</div></body></html>"};` are bad. You should write `char htmlend[] = "</div></body></html>";` etc. What compiler are you using ?

Comment: This code compiles without errors on gcc.  Why do you think `fwrite` only accepts 2 arguments?

Comment: So you mean you are having problems with `fopen` not `fwrite` as stated in the first sentence of your question. Anyway, the obvious solution is to use `snprintf` to construct each filename string with a different `n` value and pass that string into `fopen`.

Comment: im using visual studio, if i use the commented code it says " lambda text will be skipped"

Comment: Why end `"<img src='\\C:\\Users\\Sparkm4n\\Desktop\\material\\\0"` with 2 null characters?  `fwrite(image, 1, strlen(image), write);` is not writing either of those 2 null characters.

Comment: the \0 is the end of array, because without \0 i get "undefined behaviour"

Comment: `char imageend[] = {"'><br>\0"};` also ends with 2 null characters and `fwrite(imageend, 1, 1+strlen(imageend), write);` writes 1 of them.  **Very unusual** to write a null character to a text file.

Comment: @Sparkm4n What is your question?

Comment: @Sparkm4n Also, how do you know you get "undefined behaviour" if you don't type \0 at the end of your string?

Comment: The question is not why there is an ending null character, these question is why 2 of them?

Comment: because i noticed white spaces in the output so i tried to fix it with \0

Comment: @Sparkm4n For the third time, what is your actual question that you want to know the answer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code but the logic is globally good.

I see that you have commented the line aimed to create the HTML file associated to the current image pointed by `line`. In fact, you need `snprintf` to do the formatting you want to do. This functions acts like `printf` but writes into a buffer instead of writing on the standard output.

So, I have renamed some variables but for the other changes, I have added a corresponding comment. I have reduced changes into the imperative ones only, though, to keep your code as unchanged as possible. Read these comments to understand why your code doesn't work.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main() {
    // <UPDATE label="standard string initialization syntax">
    char html_start[] = "<html_start><head><style>img{height:40px;width:40px;}</style></head><body><div align='center'>";
    char html_end[] = "</div></body></html_start>";
    char image_start[] = "<img src='C:\\Users\\Sparkm4n\\Desktop\\material\\";
    char image_end[] = "'><br>";
    // </UPDATE>

    FILE *f_dateien;
    FILE *f_pics_html;
    f_dateien = fopen("dateien.txt", "r");
    if (f_dateien == NULL) {
        printf("f_dateien error!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("file opened\n");
    }
    char line[200] = "";
    int n = 0;
    f_pics_html=fopen("C:\\Users\\Sparkm4n\\Desktop\\material\\pics.html", "w");
    printf("pics.html opened at %p\n", f_pics_html);
    fwrite(html_start, 1, strlen(html_start), f_pics_html);
    while (fgets(line, 200, f_dateien)) {
        // <UPDATE>
        // fgets also reads the \n of a line
        // Assuming that each line never exceeds 200 characters,
        // We can do this to remove that useless \n if it is present:
        int len = strlen(line);
        if (len > 0 && line[len - 1] == '\n') {
            line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
            len--;
        }
        // Ignore empty lines
        if (len == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        // </UPDATE>

        printf("%s\n", line);

        ++n;

        // <UPDATE>
        // _snprintf provides a correct way to format a string
        // It's the Microsoft's attempt to mimic the standard snprintf function
        char f_one_pic_html_name[260];
        _snprintf(f_one_pic_html_name, 260, "C:\\Users\\Sparkm4n\\Desktop\\material\\pics\\%d.html", n);

        FILE *f_one_pic_html=fopen(f_one_pic_html_name, "w");
        // </UPDATE>

        // <UPDATE label="start the html like we've done with pics.html">
        fwrite(html_start, 1, strlen(html_start), f_one_pic_html);
        // </UPDATE>

        fwrite(image_start, 1, strlen(image_start), f_one_pic_html);
        fwrite(line,1, strlen(line), f_one_pic_html);
        // <UPDATE label="write strlen(image_end) chars, not strlen + 1">
        fwrite(image_end, 1, strlen(image_end), f_one_pic_html);
        // </UPDATE>

        // <UPDATE label="write the image in pics.html too">
        fwrite(image_start, 1, strlen(image_start), f_pics_html);
        fwrite(line,1, strlen(line), f_pics_html);
        fwrite(image_end, 1, strlen(image_end), f_pics_html);
        // </UPDATE>

        // <UPDATE label="end html">
        fwrite(html_end, 1, strlen(html_end), f_one_pic_html);
        fclose(f_one_pic_html);
        // </UPDATE>
    }

    fwrite(html_end, 1, strlen(html_end), f_pics_html);
    fclose(f_pics_html);

    printf("%d found\n", n);
    fclose(f_dateien);

    return 0;
}
```

That done, you can now enhance your code like:

- using good variable names
- good code formatting
- storing the return of strlen in a variable rather than calling it many times
- better file parsing
- casting a pointer to `void *` when using `%p`
- etc.